# App does not support leaderboards - iMessage App

Tags: ios, game-center, leaderboard, imessage-extension, game-center-leaderboard

I have an iMessage app, and trying to get Leaderboard scores. I am getting error:

> Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation could not
>   be completed due to an error communicating with the server."
>   UserInfo={GKServerStatusCode=5043, NSLocalizedDescription=The
>   requested operation could not be completed due to an error
>   communicating with the server., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000ed3960
>   {Error Domain=GKServerErrorDomain Code=5043 "status = 5043, MyApp does
>   not support leaderboards" UserInfo={GKServerStatusCode=5043,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=status = 5043, MyApp does not support
>   leaderboards}}}

Please note that my app is live, game center is enabled and it has been days since leaderboards were created on iTunes Connect.

```
func getScoreLeaderboard(leaderboardIdentifier:String, completion:@escaping ((_ resultScore:GKScore?) -> Void)) {

    let leaderBoardRequest = GKLeaderboard()

    leaderBoardRequest.identifier = leaderboardIdentifier

    leaderBoardRequest.loadScores {

        (resultGKScore, error) in

        guard error == nil && resultGKScore != nil else {

            completion(nil)

            return

        }

        completion(leaderBoardRequest.localPlayerScore)

    }

}
```

I have a doubt, but not sure it can be the problem. Problem might be:

I have an iMessage app with Bundle ID e.g. `com.mygame`. On iTunes Connect, I made a test app to check in app purchase issue encountered. And its Bundle ID is `com.mygame.MessagesExtension`.

I think that it is trying to get Leaderboard from app with extension bundle ID. Can it be possible? Since my app `com.mygame` is live, I am unable to delete extension test app, though it is not being used.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that Leaderboard was being retrieved from test app instead of actual one. I end up implementing scores management via Firebase instead of Game Center. Apple customer services are pathetic.